# How to send files to the trash can without the confirmation dialog

Tags: lubuntu, pcmanfm

If I delete a file, the following message appears on the screen:

[image: screenshot]

How could disable that message and send the file straight to the trash can?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try this:

**1)** Open Pcmanfm (File Manager) and go to **Edit > Preferences**

[image]

### For Lubuntu 12.04 to 13.10

Uncheck **Confirm before deleting files**

[image]

### For Lubuntu 14.04

Uncheck **Confirm before moving files into "trash can"**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can also delete a file without moving to trash by using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> shortcut.

Comment: Just to be clear, you still get a prompt, but you don't need to take the extra step of emptying the trash later.

Answer (score -1):

Nautilus>edit>preferences>behavior

There's a pair of checkboxes near the bottom of that panel to choose "delete" behavior.

Comment: Lubuntu uses Pcmanfm as default file manager, not Nautilus.